# intensity to RGB color convertor, matlab

Tags: matlab

I have color vector =[0.....1]. I want to convert it to RGB code such that

```
color_vector =[0.....1] % o for blue, .5 for green and 1 for red
R=255,0,0
G=0,255,0
B=0,0,255
```

Is there any matlab command(which I could not found) to do it or code.

Another issue is that I want to make my own range for green color (.45-.55) all should be green color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CC and it works well.I can interpolate the  colors.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you describe is a `colormap` - but you need to index your color vector for 
that.

Incidentally `hsv2rgb` produces a similar color mapping. But starting from red:

> As the hue varies from 0 to 1, the resulting color varies from
>       red, through yellow, green, cyan, blue and magenta, back to red.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to linearly interpolate between the colors, for intensity values that are not exactly 0, 0.45-0.55, or 1? If so, you can use [real2rgb](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23342-real2rgb-colormaps) (on the MATLAB File Exchange), as follows:

```
I = rand(100, 100);                               % Input data
cmap = [1 0 0 45; 0 1 0 10; 0 1 0 45; 0 0 1 0];   % Colormap defining the transformation
RGB = real2rgb(I, cmap);                          % Do the conversion
```

Comment: @ user664303 I have a vector [ x,y,z,intensity] and I want [x,y,z,rgb]. I donot know how to use real2rgb.